# Invertible maps

Tags: measure-theory, jacobian, pushforward

I am not an expert in the field and would appreciate any help with this problem. Suppose $(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ is a probability space, and that the measure $\mu$ is continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure and admits a density $f(x\in\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is strictly positive $f(x)>0$ and finite.

Let $T:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{X}$ be a measure preserving map in a sense that $\int_{\mathcal{H}}d\mu(T(x))=\int_{\mathcal{H}}d\mu(x)$ for all $\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$. Can we say that $T$ is invertible? I was thinking along the line that if $J$ is the Jacobian of the transformation from $x$ to $T(x)$, one can argue $f(T(x))|\textrm{det}(J)|=f(x)$ and since $f$ is non-zero, the Jacobian $J$ should be invertible, and thus $T$. Does that make sense? Or is there a better way to to argue about invertibility of $T$?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the settings that are discussed are slightly different (e.g. here we don't know anything about $T$ but the density $f$ is assumed to have nice properties).

Comment: $T$ looks a bit like an isometry (the fact that $|\det(\nabla T)| = 1$ is a property of isometries), and isometries are always invertible ($d(f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $x=y$) But of course you have volume preservation and not distance preservation. But maybe there is a connection

Comment: looking at the link by @geetha290krm, there the density is equal to 1, I doubt that the density has any influence on this. This is likely hopeless.

Comment: I think what we can say, probably, is that if $T$ is smooth then it should be invertible, since $f$ is non zero, and the Jacobian can be inverted.

Answer (score 0):

(Would be more appropriate as a comment, cannot do that yet)

Measure preservingness is generally defined as having
$$T^{-1}\mathcal{H}~=~ \mathcal{H},\quad\forall\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{A}\,\text{measurable}.$$
(Check whether that coincides with what you wrote.) This is because measurability of $T$ only insures that measurability of $\mathcal{H}$ implies measurability of $T^{-1}\mathcal{H}$, but doesn't say anything about measurability of $T\mathcal{H}$. Knowing $T$ is measure preserving (in the sense of the definition that I provided), doesn't tell you anything about $T$ being invertible.